# Maximizing the expected value of profit with respect to deterministic variables

Tags: probability, optimization, expected-value

I have an optimization problem of the form

$$\underset{x_k}{\max} \sum_{k=1}^{N}\mathbb{E}_{\gamma_k}[f(x_0,x_k,\gamma_k)]\\
\text{s.t.} \sum_{k=0}^{N} x_k =C\\
\forall k: x_k,\gamma_k\ge 0
$$

where all the $f(x_0,x_k,\gamma_k)$ are convex functions of the deterministic variables $(x_0,x_k)$. $\gamma_k$ are random variables and the expectation is with respect to them (if this helps, we have $f(x_0,x_k,\gamma_k) = x_k\ln\left( \gamma_k\frac{x_0}{x_k}+c_k \right)$ where $c_k$ is some given positive constant). Unfortunately the expectation makes the objective function to be a very complicated function of the deterministic variables.

How can I find the optimal value of the deterministic variables? I was thinking about using the Lagrangian dual function. Writing the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L}(x_0,\cdots,x_N,\lambda) = -\sum_{k=1}^{N}\mathbb{E}[f(x_0,x_k,\gamma_k)] -\lambda(\sum_{k=0}^{N} x_k -C)$$

and KKT conditions

$$\frac{\partial\mathbb{E}[f(x_0,x_k,\gamma_k)] }{\partial x_k}-\lambda=0 \\
\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{\partial\mathbb{E}[f(x_0,x_k,\gamma_k)] }{\partial x_0}-\lambda=0 \\
\sum_{k=0}^{N} x_k =C
$$

What can be done from here? Also Duality gap is not zero here, right (because after calculating the expectation the resulting function most likely is not convex, I think the the expectation can be expressed in terms of the hypergeometric function)?! Can we find optimal value of $x_0,\cdots,x_k,\lambda$ without calculating the value of expectation? Is there an algorithm to solve this? Is this the right approach?!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the distribution of the $\gamma_k$?  It can make a significant difference to the solution approach...

Comment: It is a gamma variable $\gamma_k\sim\text{Gamma}(\kappa_k,\theta_k)$.

Comment: I suspect there's a closed-form solution to the expected value as a function of the $x_i$, as this looks like a shifted log-gamma variate.   (If it weren't for the $c_k$, I'd be sure of it.)  A complex one, involving $\psi$ functions, but in principle something you might be able to work with.

Comment: https://www.casact.org/sites/default/files/2021-07/Log-Gamma-Distribution-Halliwell.pdf